# how to found 2 matches in regular expression

Tags: javascript

I need a regular expression for :

```
<<12.txt>> <<45.txt>
```

I have created a regular expression :

```
<<.+.txt>>
```

But this found one match in whole string but here is 2 matches:

- `<<12.txt>>`
- `<<45.txt>>`

if anyone have solution for this problem please help me out there

Comment: `<<45.txt>` isn't going to match because it only has one `>` Is that a typo?

Comment: What are you using to match the string? Are you using the String.search() function?

Comment: I am working on Adobe InDesign scripting in which I am using grep preferences

Answer (score 1):

Part of the issue is that the string you've specified wouldn't match because the second `>` is missing in `<<45.txt>`.

Also, you're using the `.` (dot) selector, and also trying to find a period. It works, but now how you think it is.

Here's the regex you want:

```
var regex = /<<\d+\.txt>>/g
```

`\d` matches only numbers

`\.` matches an actual period

`/g` means global, so it won't stop at the first match

## Practice Regular Expressions

https://regexr.com/43bs4

## Demo

```js
var string = "<<12.txt>> <<45.txt>>";
var regex = /<<\d+\.txt>>/g;
var matches = string.match(regex);

console.log(matches);
```

P.S., if you actually want to match with 1 `>` or 2 `>>`, you can with:

```
var regex = /<<\d+\.txt>>?/g
```

`?` optionally matches the character right before it

Answer (score 0):

```
/<<.+.txt>>/gm
```

g is for global (will search through entire source)

m is for multi line search support

Comment: I assume OP wants to escape the `.` before the `txt` so it should be like this: `/<<.+\.txt>>/g`. Also, I think you should remove the space at the end of the regex.

Comment: You're right about extra space, but I can't see where you got escaping a dot before extension.

Comment: I assume the OP doesn't want things like this `<<42Mtxt>>` to be captured. Maybe my assumption is wrong. [see example](https://regexr.com/43egp)